# Asymptotic behaviour of a Dirichlet series as t goes to infinity Titchmarsh the theory of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, dirichlet-series

I am stuck on a proof from a proposition on Titchmarsh's book "The Theory of Functions", at page 297 which says that for a Dirichlet series we have: $f(s)=O(|t|^{1-(\sigma-\sigma_0)+\epsilon})$ as $|t|\rightarrow\infty\quad \forall\sigma\in(\sigma_0,\sigma_0+1)$. The proof begins with the assumption that $\sigma_0=0$ so that we can obtain then the general case by changing the variable in the Dirichlet series. My question is: why we suppose first in the proof that $\sum a_n$ is convergent? We don't know generally if a Dirichlet series is convergent or not at $\sigma=\sigma_0$. The only thing that we know is that it is convergent for $\sigma=\sigma_0+\epsilon\quad \forall\epsilon>0$. I cannot understand how it turns out that $\sum a_n$ is convergent. Maybe it is a quite easy question, but I am really stuck on this.

Comment: @T. Titchmarsh **supposes**...but later he does the general case. What's the problem?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You probably want to show for $\Re(s) > 0$ : $\zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s-1} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}(n^{-s}- x^{-s})dx $   where $\int_n^{n+1}(n^{-s}- x^{-s})dx= \int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x s t^{-s-1}dtdx$ is $ \mathcal{O}(n^{-s})$ and $\mathcal{O}(s n^{-s-1})$ thus $\mathcal{O}(s^a n^{-s-a})$ for any $a \in (0,1)$, which gives the result.

Comment: In the general case we will have the hypothesis according with Titchmarsh that for $\sigma=\sigma_0$ the series is convergent($\sum\frac{a_n}{n^s}=\sum\frac{a'_n}{n^{s'}} where a'_n=a_nn^{s_0},s'=s-s_0$).If we take the zeta function then we have that $\sum a'_n=\sum \frac{1}{n}=\infty$ so we can't suppose generally in the begining of the proof that $\sum a_n$ is convergent.This assumption gives that $a_n,s_n$ are bounded something we need to continue the proof.

Comment: Maybe i have to take two occasions whether $\sum a_n$ is convergent or not?? @DonAntonio

Comment: @T.Karawolf That's apparently the way Titchmarsh did it in his book.

Comment: thank you but it is not very clearly in the book